# Can Phosphogycolate buildup in a plant kill it?

Tags: cell-biology, photosynthesis, cellular-respiration

I'm trying to think of some things for the science fair, for part of my experiment I need to know if Phosphogycolate build up in a plant can kill it. Also, are there any chemicals that may disrupt the enzymes which break down phosphogycolate. Thanks!

Comment: Too late to tell you, but phosphogycolate doesn’t exist.

Answer (score -1):

Phosphogycolate can break down enzymes needed in the Calvin Cycle along with other enzymes in a plant so that is a yes.l.